# Return statement not returning as expected

Tags: java, recursion, return, linear-search

Why does the code below return -1 instead of `arr.length-1`? If the `find()` method is looking for 24, it should return 5, but now it returns -1. It should only return -1 if n is not found in arr.

```
public class linearArraySearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = new int[]{ 12, 42, 56, 7, 99, 24, 6, 1, 5 };
        System.out.println( find(numbers, 24) );
    }

    public static int find( int[] arr, int n ){
        if( arr[arr.length-1] == n ){
            return arr.length-1;
        }else if( arr.length > 1 && arr[arr.length-1] != n ){
            int[] temp = new int[arr.length-1];
            for( int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++ ){
                temp[i] = arr[i];
            }
            find( temp, n );            
        }        
        return -1;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you required to do it with recursion? should be so much simple using only a for loop

Comment: Should `find (temp, n)` be `return find(temp n)` ? Otherwise you are ignoring the result of your recursion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are ignoring the value returned by your recursive call.

You should change

```
find( temp, n );
```

to

```
return find( temp, n );
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want to actually do something with the result of `find( temp, n );` but currently you don't. So your function only returns `arr.length - 1` if `n` is the last element of `arr` and `-1` in *all* other cases.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning only two values from your function.

```
return arr.length-1;
```

in case `arr[arr.length-1] == n`

and `return -1`

So, you will only get the correct answer, if the number you are trying to find is located at the last index of your array.

About

```
else if( arr.length > 1 && arr[arr.length-1] != n ){
```

You do not need `arr[arr.length-1] != n` since you already have checked it and if the execution comes here, that means, `arr[arr.length-1]] != n`, otherwise, you have been returned from the first `if`.

You need to return the result of your function which you probably forgot or didn't realize to do.

`return find (temp, n);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class linearArraySearch {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = new int[]{ 12, 42, 56, 7, 99, 24, 6, 1, 5 };
    System.out.println( find(numbers, 24) );
}

public static int find( int[] arr, int n ){
    if( arr[arr.length-1] == n ){
        return arr.length-1;
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < (arr.length-1); i++ ){
        if(arr[i] == n) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}    
}
```